# How to redirect Visualforce page automatically

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, controller

I have custom button which when clicked redirects to VF page, VF page calls some controller,

But I want as soon as custom button is clicked it should process to VF page waits for 2 secs and then redirect back to detail page of the record.

How to achieve that? Not getting any help from google

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the most simple way I could imagine. Other alternatives abound, as well.

```
<apex:page controller="Controller" action="{!action}">
    <script>
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.history.go(-1);
        }, 2000); // 2 seconds
    </script>
    We did as you asked. Redirecting back in 2 seconds.
</apex:page>
```

As a side note, I'd avoid DML this way, because it does open up the possibility of XSS attacks (however unlikely that would be). Instead, offer the button here as a means of confirmation, then return when you're done. Alternatively, simply perform the work from the button itself. There's really no need to show a page for just two seconds.

---

You can also show a waiting dialog while you're waiting:

```
<apex:page controller="Controller">
Please wait...
<script>
function done() {
    window.history.go(-1); // Or elsewhere
}
</script>
<apex:form>
<apex:actionFunction name="doAction" action="{!doAction}" oncomplete="done()" />
</apex:form>
<script>
doAction();
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Feel free to use a spinner or something instead of just a generic "please wait" message to give the illusion that something is happening (which, something *is* happening, but we want the user to be reassured).

Comment: fox, the idea behind showing page to the user is it show them there record is processing and if it successfully updated boom ..the detail page is shown...

Comment: @ashish In that case, you'd probably want to move this to an action function. It doesn't need to be 2 seconds, just as long as it takes... I'll update with example.

Comment: True, Action sounds good , I haven't used it ever so was not aware of it .. But thanks for giving me so many options .. that was really awesome... I definitely owe you beer for sure...  :)

Comment: Another option would be to call a method in the controller that will return a page reference and do the redirect on the server side.

Comment: Nice answer @sfdcfox! One could seemingly easily modify the method from this [blog post for a progress bar](http://eternussolutions.blogspot.in/2015/01/fun-with-progress-bars.html) inside of a controller as @Bachovski suggests to give the visual impression something was happening and control the timing of it.